# Enable MySQL at system startup

Tags: linux, boot, services

I'm running a ubuntu 10.04 box.
I want to enable Mysql on startup.
Typically, I used the following command:

> #update-rc.d mysql defaults

Mysql still doesn't start when system boots.
Suggestions?

Comment: How did you install it? like.. from apt? or from any other source.

Comment: From the repositories (apt)

Comment: Then check out the command services --status-all. Does it show the mysql service? Probably you have already done that.. Still to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) to control the behaviour of startup services. You can find the conf scripts at /etc/init (e. g. mysql.conf).

The MySQL script requires a net-device-up and this can cause some trouble. Check this part of the script:

```
start on (net-device-up
         and local-filesystems
         and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
```

You can safely remove the net-device-up directive.

```
start on (local-filesystems
         and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
```

Now, the script only depends on runlevel and mounted partitions/fs. If after that the problem still persists, you should look for lock/permission problem in your log files.